# AWS Route 53 DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am trying to give my API Gateway a custom domain name. I have my domain name in hosted zones, and alias target is set correctly. When I check response in aws manually I get NOERROR DNS response code, but when I send a request I get Connection refused error. I'm new to this can you tell what I'm doing wrong ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you create a custom domain name in API gateway that matches the domain name you're trying to use? Then use that as the value

Comment: yes I have created the domain name

Comment: And you set your Route 53 value to the value of the `API Gateway domain name`. This will either be a cloudfront distribution name or a domain containing the `execute-api.$REGION.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: Yes I have set the Alias Target value to the domain name

Comment: certificate using is same name as domain name ?